# How do I assign the same property to a list of winform classes?

Tags: c#

I have an arraylist of all a bunch of winform controls (textboxes, checkboxes, radio buttons, etc).

I am trying to enable/disable them all at once.

Code is as below:

```
Button button = new Button();
Label label = new Label();
Listview listview = new ListView();

ArrayList controlList = new ArrayList();

controlList.add(button);
controlList.add(label);
controlList.add(listview);

foreach(object o in controlList) {
    o.enabled = false;
}
```

But of course, this wouldn't work, since the class object does not have the property "enabled" in it.

What should I do to make this work?

Comment: Don't use `ArrayList`.  Ever.  Use `List` instead.

Comment: All you really ***have*** to do (aside from fixing the syntactical errors) is use `Control` instead of `object` in your `foreach` loop statement, because all the objects in your ArrayList inherit from `Control`, and because `Control` has an `Enabled` property, but `object` does not. But you should move into the new decade and use a `List<Control>` instead of `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a `List<Control>`. This is the base class of all `System.Windows.Controls`. You can iterate over all properties of the Control type:

```
Button button = new Button();
Label label = new Label();
Listview listview = new ListView();

var controlList = new List<Control>();
controlList.Add(button);
controlList.Add(label);
controlList.Add(listview);

foreach(var o in controlList) {
    o.Enabled = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
o.enabled = false;
```

To

```
(o as Control.enabled = false;
```

Comment: You left off your `)`.